# How to play the videos using Html5 in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html5-video

i have a asp.net mvc3 web application in this i have use the Htlml5 controls.I want play the Video in this mvc3 application using html5 for this i have try for this ,when run the page just it show the blak window and controls there is no visible the video i have declare like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IlifeLooks.Models.User>" %>

       <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
        Window
      </asp:Content>
   <asp:content id="Content2" contentplaceholderid="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Window</h2>
         <video width="560" height="340" controls>
    <source src="../../Videos/Nenu Nuvvuantu - Orange - MyInfoland.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="../../Videos/Meray Haath.avi" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
<video id="myvideo" runat="server" width="300px" height="500px" autoplay="autoplay"
    controls="controls" src="~/Videos/Nenu Nuvvuantu - Orange - MyInfoland.mp4">
</video>
```

What can i change in my code please help me....

Comment: Can you put the URLs in the browser and see that they download?

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response,i can't get u url's means...?Here i have assign the source from server path

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
src=foldername/video.mp4
```